# Laravel doesn't generate a new key because can't find APP_KEY

Tags: php, laravel, docker, laravel-artisan

I need to clone an existing project into my new **Docker**-environment , but running `php artisan key:generate` always fails due to missing `APP_KEY` in **.env**, but it exists there and empty!

I tried `php artisan config:clear` and `php artisan config:cached`, but didn't help as well.

Why could it happen and could it be a problem with my Docker container?

[image: laravel app key error]

Comment: Do you copy your .env file in your docker container or do you use a local volume? Verify if the file is indeed in the container

Comment: Empty environment variables are not always the same as no environment variables.

Comment: Did you found out the answer? I am in the exact same situation...